# Google Analytics API - Retrieve Index/Name of Custom Dimension or how many used up

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a service that pushes data into GA Custom Dimensions/Variables. Before I push I want to know which Custom Dimensions are available to push to and I also don't want to duplicate so if I have the unique name (because I would create unique names) of a Dimension I can check that too.

Anyone know how this can be done? I have searched through the API docs and it doesn't seem like it's anywhere.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Core reporting api to get the names of the `dimensions` [Custom Variables or Columns - Dimensions & Metrics Reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=custom_variables_or_columns&jump=ga_customvarnamexx)  Then select then you can run a request against it to see what values are already stored.

Make sure you look into a [service account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount) don't go with normal Oauth2.

Comment: I tried the Hello Analytics Tutorial and got dimension data. It doesn't seem like I can just query which Dimensions are available, only which Dimensions have data and query the details of the data such as pageviews. Just because a dimension has data doesn't mean it's not being used...any other ideas?